# how to make an iframe work on phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, iframe, cordova, iframe-app

Im doing an app that will use an iframe my question is

Why do I have to change in config.xml

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
```

To:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

In order to make frames work on `phonegap`